# Why do I get this error when importing MetPy submodules?

Tags: metpy

I just installed MetPy for the first time using

```
conda install -c conda-forge metpy
```

under Mac OS X 10.14 (Mojave).  I appear to have gotten `metpy-0.11.1`

The following line then generates the error diagnotics copied at the bottom.

```
from metpy.plots import StationPlot
```

I get the exact same error (`TypeError: find_intersections takes 5 parameters, but 3 units were passed`) if I instead try

```
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
```

I don't get an error if I import the entire module using

```
import metpy
```

I have never before experienced an import error with any established Python package, so any help debugging my setup would be appreciated.

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 from metpy.plots import StationPlot
> 2
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/scipy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/metpy/plots/**init**.py
> in 
> 11 from .ctables import *  # noqa: F403
> 12 from .declarative import *  # noqa: F403
> ---> 13 from .skewt import *  # noqa: F403
> 14 from .station_plot import *  # noqa: F403
> 15 from .wx_symbols import *  # noqa: F403
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/scipy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/metpy/plots/skewt.py
> in 
> 27
> 28 from ._util import colored_line
> ---> 29 from ..calc import dewpoint, dry_lapse, moist_lapse, vapor_pressure
> 30 from ..calc.tools import _delete_masked_points
> 31 from ..deprecation import metpyDeprecation
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/scipy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/metpy/calc/**init**.py
> in 
> 5
> 6 from .basic import *  # noqa: F403
> ----> 7 from .cross_sections import *  # noqa: F403
> 8 from .indices import *  # noqa: F403
> 9 from .kinematics import *  # noqa: F403
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/scipy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/metpy/calc/cross_sections.py
> in 
> 12
> 13 from .basic import coriolis_parameter
> ---> 14 from .tools import first_derivative
> 15 from ..package_tools import Exporter
> 16 from ..xarray import check_axis, check_matching_coordinates
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/scipy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/metpy/calc/tools.py
> in 
> 104 @preprocess_xarray
> 105 @units.wraps(('=A', '=B'), ('=A', '=B', '=B'))
> --> 106 def find_intersections(x, a, b, direction='all', log_x=False):
> 107     """Calculate the best estimate of intersection.
> 108
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/scipy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pint/registry_helpers.py
> in decorator(func)
> 246             raise TypeError(
> 247                 "%s takes %i parameters, but %i units were passed"
> --> 248                 % (func.**name**, count_params, len(args))
> 249             )
> 250
>
> TypeError: find_intersections takes 5 parameters, but 3 units were
> passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have too recent a version of Pint installed (>= 0.10) for that older version of MetPy. I'd update at least metpy with `conda install -c conda-forge metpy=0.12.2`. You can try updating everything with `conda update -c conda-forge --all`.

Comment: That solved my original problem, but now I get "module 'cartopy.feature' has no attribute 'Scaler'" when importing StationPlot.

Comment: Sounds like your install of CartoPy is also out of date--`Scaler` has been in CartoPy since 0.17.0, released 2 years ago. Need to update with `conda install -c conda-forge cartopy=0.18.0`.

Comment: There must be something broken in my environment, because it's refusing to advance CartoPy past 0.16.0.

Comment: If you haven't put conda-forge in your default channel configuration, you could try this: `conda config --add channels conda-forge`, `conda config --set channel_priority strict`, `conda update conda`, and finally `conda update --all`. That should update settings, update Conda, and then update all your packages.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Conda found a lot of package conflicts in my current environment but offered no solutions, so I'm creating a whole new environment specifically for metpy and installing required packages from scratch.  Hopefully that cleans everything up.  Also adding the config commands you mentioned.